# How to exclude some @Configuration and only import them using @Import in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a spring-boot webapp which has the following package structure..

```
- com.myname.configs
    - CommonConfiguration.java  
    - DevConfiguration.java  
    - ProdConfiguration.java
    - SomeOtherConfiguration.java
- com.myname.profiles
    - DevProfile.java
    - ProdProfile.java
```

All of these classes are @Configuration classes but the DevProfile.java and ProdProfile.java also have the @Profile and @Import annotations.

CommonConfiguration..

```
@Configuration  
public class CommonConfiguration {  
    //commmon configs / beans..  
}
```

DevConfiguration..

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevConfiguration {

    @Bean
    //dev specific beans..
}
```

DevProfile..

```
@Configuration  
@Import(value = {CommonConfiguration.class, DevConfiguration.class})  
@Profile("dev")  
public class DevProfile {}
```

ProdProfile..

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = {CommonConfiguration.class, ProdConfiguration.java})
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdProfile {}
```

For some reason, even with -Dspring.profile.active=prod, the beans for DevConfiguration are created. The only workaround is to add a @Profile("dev") annotation to DevConfiguration.java

Is there a way to only create the beans for classes in the @Import annotations? It seems logical to manage the Imports in one Profile class than add the Profile to various Configuration classes.

I'm looking for a way to do what @Aaron Digulla suggested in #1 here [How to exclude some @Configuration file in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119446/how-to-exclude-some-configuration-file-in-spring)

Comment: I think if the @Configuration classes are in the component scanning path they will be created unless you tell the container to exclude them. How are you annotating DevConfiguration?

Comment: More importantly: are @Configuration classes in the wrong profile?

Comment: Which packages are you scanning?

Comment: @efekctive I've added the DevConfiguration class details. I'm not manually using the ComponentScan annotation anywhere. I do think that the SpringBootApplication annotation might be doing it. How do I change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use config-classes`(CommonConfiguration`,`DevConfiguration` and etc.) only by importing in profile-classes (`DevProfile` and etc.) then you just may remove `@Configuration` from config-classes.
In this case beans from config-classes will be created only via active profile-class (now config-classes and profile-classes are both scanned by spring for beans but `@Profile("...")` affect only to profile-classes).

Comment: This is the most elegant and simple answer. You're absolutely correct! haha.. why didn't I think of that..

Comment: I was about to post the code for this but no need for it.

Comment: This is not feasible if you are using code imported from dependencies that is not part of your source code

Answer (score 2):

Actually, shortly after posting the comment I found the answer. It is [Kirby's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266531/kirby) answer here [Exclude subpackages from Spring autowiring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725192/exclude-subpackages-from-spring-autowiring)

In my case I've added this after the @SpringBootApplication annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myname" },
              excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern = "com.myname.configs.*"))
public class DemoWebappApplication {...}
```

With this, the profile classes are being wired along with the @Imports in them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) annotation in below link (16.2 section)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html